# I am getting an error " [Error] ld returned 1 exit status" in C++ . Help me with this

Tags: c++, arrays

I am making a program in C++ in DevC++ for finding missing number from `1` to `n`th digits but now I am getting an error:

> [Error] ld returned 1 exit status.

You can see my program and help me with this.
This program is now valid for `100` digits only.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class miss_number
    {
        public:
        static int arr[100];
        int miss;
        int n;

        public:
            void displayBoard();
            void getInput();
            void findMissing();
            void displayMissing();  
    };
    void miss_number :: displayBoard()
    {
        cout<<"The program for Finding Missing Number Between 1-100 digit";
    }
    void miss_number :: getInput()
    {
        int i;
        cout<<"\nEnter how many digits :";
        cin>>n;
        cout<<"\nEnter the number between 1-100 digit :";
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }   
    }
    void miss_number :: findMissing()
    {
        int i,total,totalOfArray=0;
        total = n*(n+1)/2;
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            totalOfArray = totalOfArray + arr[i];
        }
        miss = total - totalOfArray;

    }
    void miss_number :: displayMissing()
    {
        cout<<"\nMissing number :"<<miss;
    }

    int main()
    {
        miss_number o;
        o.displayBoard();
        o.getInput();
        o.findMissing();
        o.displayMissing();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't the link error associated with a message, something like : error LNK2001: unresolved symbol "public: static int * miss_number::arr" (?arr@miss_number@@2PAHA) ? Lokk in DevC++ Console for further verbose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the declaration

```cpp
static int arr[100];
```

Since you declared it as static, you must define it outside the class:

```
int miss_number::arr[100];
```

This way, the program compiles and links. If using C++17, you can also just declare it as `inline static` and the effect would be the same.

If you just remove the `static` in your declaration without adding anything else, it also compiles, and it should be the correct way to do this in your case, because `arr` is a member of the instanced object. This way, you'd be able to create multiple instances of the class and they'd each have its own `arr`.

With that said, you don't need to return `arr` in `getInput` and then repass it to `findMissing`, since it's visible from inside all member functions of the class. Just removing all parameters from `findMissing` in all instances fixes this.

Comment: @KrishnanandPathak if this answers your question, press the green tick on the left to mark the problem as solved.